# The name for planar graph where the position of vertices and shape of the edges matter

Tags: graph-theory, euclidean-geometry, planar-graphs

How would you call a geometric object, which is topologically a planar graph, but its plane coordinates of the vertices and the curves of the edges matter?

Imagine the map of roads in a city. Not only the connectivity between road junctions are important, but also how the road actually goes from A to B.

I thought I can call it “geometric graph”, but this term likely means [something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_graph_theory). I also consider “planar graph embedding”. But I worry that the  “coordinate-awareness” of this object is not highlighted enough.

[image: Maps of road in Amsterdam]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically saying that you have a planar graph $G=(V,E)$ which means that $G$ admits an embedding in $\mathbb{C}$ (what this means is purposefully a bit vague here). However, you're caring about a *particular* embedding $\varphi$ which is a particular pair of injective maps $\varphi_1:V\to \mathbb{C}$ and $\varphi_2: E\to C([0,1])$ such that:

$i)$ $\varphi(e)$ is simple for every $e$.

$ii)$ As oriented edges, $\varphi_2((v,w);0)=\varphi_1(v)$ and $\varphi_2((v,w);1)=\varphi_1(w)$

$iii)$ For $e\neq f$, we have that $\varphi_2(e;[0,1])\cap \varphi_2(f;[0,1])\subseteq \{\varphi_2(e;0),\varphi_2(e;1)\}\cap \{\varphi_2(f;0),\varphi_2(f;1)\}$

At least that is a fairly reasonable definition of what a planar embedding of a graph is. The point of the matter is that you want to *fix* an embedding as opposed to just knowing, abstractly, that $G$ is planar.

It also seems to be relevant to you, since $C([0,1])$ carries a *curve*-length, this also makes $(V,E)$ a weighted graph by declaring the weight of $e$ to be the curve-length of $\varphi_2(e)$.

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean that you advise me to go with the term "graph embedding"? The length of the edge is one of many possible characteristics of the edge (it can be mean curvature, average quality of the road, mean direction etc), which are all the functions of $\varphi_i$. So instead of appending the set of certain characteristics to the edge, I want to append the whole shape itself.

Comment: In that case I would use the term embedded graph, yes. In fact it sounds like you're interested in your graph as a CW-complex (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex) with only $0$ and $1$ cells up to *diffeomorphism* type (to the extend that that's sensible) as opposed to the usual idea of only looking at them up to homeomorphism or homotopy type.

Comment: Thank you! I am also interested in 2 cells, but that's another story.